# How to select a <li> item from a <ul> by findElememt(By.xpath("locator"));

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to automate the  and want the 2nd item to be selected when div is poped up,but not able to do..I want to select 'Mr.' instead of '--None--'.please help.Html code is

```html
<div class="select-options popupTargetContainer uiPopupTarget uiMenuList uiMenuList--default uiMenuList--left uiMenuList-short" data-aura-rendered-by="191:2436;a" data-aura-class="uiPopupTarget uiMenuList uiMenuList--default uiMenuList--left uiMenuList-short" aria-labelledby="170:2436;a" style="width: 347.5px; max-width: 347.5px; min-width: 200px; opacity: 1; position: absolute; left: 311px; top: 74px;" id="191:2436;a">
 <div class="select-options" role="menu" data-aura-rendered-by="185:2436;a">
  <!--render facet: 186:2436;a-->
  <ul class="scrollable" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="187:2436;a" data-scoped-scroll="true">
   <!--render facet: 2466:0-->
   <li role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="2470:0" class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="2471:0" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" title="--None--" aria-checked="true" class="selected"><b></b>--None--</a>
   </li>
        <li role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="2476:0" class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="2477:0" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" title="Mr."aria-checked="false"><b></b>Mr.</a>
   </li>
   <li role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="2482:0" class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="2483:0" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" title="Ms."aria-checked="false"><b></b>Ms.</a>
   </li>
   <li role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="2488:0" class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="2489:0" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" title="Mrs."aria-checked="false"><b></b>Mrs.</a></li>
   <li role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="2494:0" class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="2495:0" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" title="Dr."aria-checked="false"><b></b>Dr.</a>
   </li>
   <li role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="2500:0" class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="2501:0" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" title="Prof."aria-checked="false"><b></b>Prof.</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here xpath of upper `<div>` is `html/body/div[9]` and Xpath for `<li>` is `html/body/div[9]/div/ul/li[3]/a` . So `driver.findElement(By.Xpath("html/body/div[9]"))`is located but the `<li>` is not selected automatically. As i want to select the Ms. which is `li[3]`

Answer (score 0):

If the upper div is `div[9]` try the following xpath

For searching Ms.

`driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//div[9]//div//ul//li[3]//a"))`

For searching Mr.

`driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//div[9]//div//ul//li[2]//a"))`

Comment: Can u please explain why ".//div[9]//div//ul//li[2]//a".in this // is used? And also  why not whole xpath ".html/body/div[9]/div/ul/li[2]/a" didnot work? .

Comment: They are both similar. I have just optimizing the /html/body part which is not necessary to write.  If you used /html/body/div[9]/div/ul/li[2]/a (observe the '/' carefully in front of html then it would work

Comment: Every time i am loading the page the <div> is changing ,how to stop this,for the first time its showing div[9],and again when reloaded,it sshowing div[10],in thi scase how the path will be find out?The above example is  by taking the absoulte Xpath..When i am taking Partial path every time its showing different one ..1st time its showing ".//*[@id='191:2145;a']" and again i reloaded the pages its showing ".//*[@id='191:2596;a']"..How to fix this? How to take Xpath which keeps changing?

Comment: It is depends on the web you are working. May be you can search with id starts with 191: if you could see that there are no other id starts with 191 or else you could find some unique element which other element don't have. I will recommend to not to use absoulate path and read a little about xPath https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp and start using it

Answer (score 0):

To select the item with text as **Ms.** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select-options']/ul//li/a[@role='menuitemradio' and contains(.,'Ms.')]")).click();
```

Comment: What if there are the two divs with the same class name like say for 1st div which is in left side in which i  want  to sleect 'Ms; and there is also a 2nd div having the same class name in which i want to select the item 'New'.For 1 div i written as per your answer which is working fine and then what to write for 2nd div to select 'New'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the other answers are being as specific as they are, perhaps I'm missing something, but this should find the element in question, and be far less fragile against page structure changes:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@role='menuitemradio' and @title='Mr.']"));
```

Even including @role here isn't necessary, but I'm doing it just to be safe.